# modal is showing same information for every button

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

My code is working but the modal is showing same information for every button. I have to refresh the page each time to get information for other button .

there's the script and modal code 
the id here is of the product fetched from database. i am new to web development still pursuing my degree.

```
 <script>
     function detailsmodal(id)
     {
         var data = {"id":id};
         jQuery.ajax({
             url : <?=BASEURL;?>+'/includes/detailmodal.php',
             method : "POST",
             data : data,
             success : function(data)
     {
         jQuery('body').append(data);
         jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
     },
             error  :function()
                {alert("something went wrong");}
         });

     }
 </script>




<?php ob_start(); ?>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="modal fade" id="details-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
         <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><?= $product['title'];?></h4>
                     </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <div class="container-fluid">
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <img src="<?= $product['image'];?>" alt="<?= $product['title'];?>" class="details img-responsive"/>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <h4>Details</h4>
                                 <p><?= $product['description'];?></p><hr>
                                 <p>Price:&#8377 <?= $product['price'];?> </p>
                                 <p>Brand: <?= $brand['brand'];?></p>
                                 </div>

                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     <button class="btn btn-warning" type="sumbit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Add to cart</button>
                 </div>
         </div>

     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: And js code for modal we should imagine?

Comment: Why do you have the `json` tag??